# Не получаеться сверстать сайт. Ищу ошибку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверху изображение. Так выглядит сайт. Делал все по видео-уроку. У него получилось "Связь со мной" в одной колонке с "Сайт на котором вы находитесь", а "Привет" в колонке с "Сайт в разработке". Ищу ошибку в коде уже час. Немогу найти.
Подскажете?

```css
.header {
  background: red;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/lMCRt5S.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.col-4 {
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.portfoliotext {
  font-family: Font;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  font-family: Font;
  color: white;
}

.links {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #450f55;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfoliotext">
          <center>Сайт на котором вы находитесь</center>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---
        --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfoliotext">
          <center>Сайт в разработке</center>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-----
     BOTTOM
     ----->
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="text2">
          <p class="text1">Связь со мной</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---
        --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="links">Привет</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: не совсем понятно как должно быть. Есть макет?

Comment: Макета нету. Но объясню.Текст "Связь со мной" должен быть ниже на фиолетовой области но под текстом "Сайт на котором вы находитесь". А "Привет" так-же только под текстом "Сайт в разработке". А у меня получилось все под текстом "Сайт на котором вы находитесь".

Comment: Из косяков которые видно сразу: 1) у Вас не хватает закрывающегося дива в самом низу. 2) У Вас 2 раза id="scroll", уникальный id может быть только 1 раз на странице.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MJ3X6NO вот так должно получиться

Comment: автор загрузи скриншот ожидаемого поведения сюда в твой вопрос та как у меня imgur.com не открывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основное изменение - flexbox для row.

```css
.header {
  background: red;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/lMCRt5S.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

.portfoliotext {
  font-family: Font;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Font;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.links {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #450f55;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт на котором вы находитесь</div>
      </div>
      <!---
        --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт в разработке</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-----
     BOTTOM
     ----->
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="text2">
          <p class="text1">Связь со мной</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---
        --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="links">
          <p class="text1">Привет</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. в .text1 есть `margin-left: 50%` - там нет точки с запятой.
2. в .text1 пропишите `margin-top: 0;` - чтобы убрать отступ.
3. Сделайте разные `id`.

Comment: Так же, рекомендую добавить в .row display: flex;